# Cannot see publicly created file in external storage on Android from computer

Tags: android

I want save a somewhat large json string to a file, then access it from my computer so I can view it and put in a json validator to find out where my problem is. This is for debugging only.
I've tried saving to internal and external storage but I cant access my file for the life of me. 
I can see it from adb shell, but when I try to adb pull it, its not there.

I can also see my file from other apps (like DropBox) on the device, but I cant see it from a computer.

This is the most recent code I tried and should put it in the public downloads folder, but its not there:

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
path.mkdir();

externalFile = new File(path,JSON_FILE_NAME);

OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(externalFile));
//write stuff
out.close()
```

I HAVE added permission to write to external storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using MTP to view the files on your PC, they will only show up once the `MediaScanner` has found them. You can use the following code to force the `MediaScanner` to scan your file:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(),
            new String[]{externalFile.toString()}, null, null);
```

Comment: Hallelujah! will award bounty once stack overflow lets me. Just curious though, would switching to PTP fix this?

Comment: p.s. this question was down voted by someone who believed that my issue was not fixable by code. Now that we know for sure this was fixable by code, I would appreciate if someone up-voted this question so that it can fairly show up in search results and potentially help others in the future.

Comment: I haven't tested the results with PTP, but I suppose the same will happen.